# Most-succinct way to search an array of hash tables for a key

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Assuming:

```
$columnArray = @(
  @{Name='COL_A';Type=[int];Measurements=@()},
  @{Name='COL_B';Type=[string];Measurements=@()},
  @{Name='COL_C';Type=[datetime];Measurements=@()}
)
```

Using the `Where-Object` command to get `COL_B`'s `Measurements` array:

```
($Fields | ? { $_.Name -eq 'COL_B' }).Measurements
```

Is there a more-succinct way of doing this?  Would a nested set of `PSCustomObject`s be a better approach?

Comment: Why not `$columnHashtable=@{COL_A=@{Type=[int];Measurements=@()};COL_B=@{Type=[string];Measurements=@()};COL_C=@{Type=[datetime];Measurements=@()}}`? That you can do that: `$columnHashtable.COL_B.Measurements`.

Comment: How about `$columnArray | % { New-Object PSObject -property $_ } | ? {$_.Name -eq 'COL_B'} | Select Measurements -ExpandProperty Measurements`

Comment: @DaveSexton `Select  -ExpandProperty Measurements`

Comment: @PetSerAl: you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in looking element by key, than `Hashtable` will be better approach than array.

```
$columnHashtable=@{
    COL_A=@{Type=[int];Measurements=@()}
    COL_B=@{Type=[string];Measurements=@()}
    COL_C=@{Type=[datetime];Measurements=@()}
}
```

With `Hashtable` you can get `Measurements` array of `COL_B` by this command:

```
$columnHashtable.COL_B.Measurements
```

And If you want to enumerate all elements in `Hashtable`, then you can use following command:

```
$columnHashtable.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object ...
```

In case if order of elements in hash table matters, you could use `[ordered]` operator before hash table literal to create `OrderedDictionary` instead of `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 4):

You could modify the array itself with a method to do the finding:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $columnArray -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name FindCol -Value { param([String]$Column) $this | ? { $_.Name -eq $Column }  }
```

Then you can do:

```
$columnArray.FindCol('COL_B').Measurements
```

Or you can do:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $columnArray -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name GetMeasurements -Value { param([String]$Column) $this | ? { $_.Name -eq $Column } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Measurements  }
```

Then:

```
$columnArray.GetMeasurements('COL_B')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take this approach:

```
$Info = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Name = "MyFieldName"
  Size = 15
  Date = Get-Date
}
```

Then these all work:

```
 $Info | Select Name, Size 
 $Info | Where ($_.date -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) 
 $Info | Sort Size -Descending | Select -First 1
```

You can also put whatever function you're using to populate the data in $Info.

```
$results = Import-CSV C:\Results.csv 

$items =  Foreach ($item in $results) {
   $thisItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
   Name = $_.name
   Size = $_.size
   Date = $_.date
   }
   $thisItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$columnArray | % {New-Object PSObject -property $_} | ? {$_.Name -eq 'COL_B'} | Select -ExpandProperty Measurements
```

It converts each element of the array to an object using the `-property` flag which saves having to explicitly define the object or use `Add-Member`